RE: ARM template for deploying a workbook template to Microsoft Sentinel
I am attempting to deploy an ARM Template (execution using PowerShell) for any Analytic Rule to a Microsoft Sentinel instance.
I have been following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-automate#next-steps.
I am struggling with ensuring the Workbook is deployed to the Microsoft Sentinel workbook gallery and NOT the Azure Monitor one.
The link includes a sample ARM template where you can add templateData (JSON code), which represents the workbook you wish to deploy.
properties": { "galleries": [ { "name": "A Workbook Template", "category": "Deployed Templates", "order": 100, "type": "workbook", "resourceType": "Azure Monitor" } ], "templateData": <PASTE-COPIED-WORKBOOK_TEMPLATE_HERE> 

I get it working to deploy to the Azure Monitor workbook gallery but not for it to be present in the Microsoft Sentinel one.
Jason

Have you tried any code so far? @Jason Smyth

I am not sure what you mean. If you mean deploying the ARM template, then yes. As I said, it deploys it to the Azure Monitor gallery through PowerShell, not the Microsoft Sentinel one.

I have the JSON code in a file. Not sure how to add an attachment...

Open the file and copy the code. Edit it in the above question. @Jason Smyth

Where I am struggling is with the direct Template and deploying that...
So, I am using this...
'"properties": {
"galleries": [
{
"name": "A Workbook Template",
"category": "Deployed Templates",
"order": 100,
"type": "workbook",
"resourceType": "Azure Monitor"
}
],
"templateData": <PASTE-COPIED-WORKBOOK_TEMPLATE_HERE>

...and then adding the JSON content for a Workbook Template at "templateData"
So, is it possible to add the Template to the Microsoft Sentinel Gallery is what I am asking?
Sorry for the previous post, I cannot 'format' the JSON...

Let me deploy in my environment and update you. @Jason Smyth

Are there any updates, @Jahnavi?

Working on your requirement only. @Jason Smyth

Have you tried this template from MSDoc. @Jason Smyth

Also have you tried by setting the gallery type as sentinel in the code. @Jason Smyth

Have you tried by changing it ? @Jason Smyth

If you want to deploy the workbook template to Microsoft sentinel instead of Azure Monitor, it all depends on the resource type basically when deploying through an ARM template.
The required type is "type": "Microsoft.SecurityInsights/contenttemplates"
Reference Microsoft community Blog for more detailed information as well as for the complete script.
If still the issue persists with the above approach, you can use the New-azresource PowerShell command with the provided resource type to achieve the requirement.
New-AzResource -ResourceGroupName xxx -ResourceType "Microsoft.SecurityInsights/contenttemplates" `
               -ResourceName "$workspaceName/Microsoft.Insights/$workbook" -Location $location `
               -PropertyObject @{
                   galleries = @(
                       @{
                           name = $workbook
                           category = $Category
                           order = 80
                           type = "workbook"
                           resourceType = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/providers"
                       }
                   )
                   templateData = TemplateData
               } -ApiVersion "2020-10-01-preview"

